# Missing out blind seats

Tags: blinds

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere, couldn't find any search results that relfect my query.

Recently joined a local texas no limt poker league competition.

During one game a player was busted out after going all in, his now vacent seat is now the BB even so no one is sitting there, I always assumed the the BB would then be moved to the next seat/person. As I thought each round must always have the minimum SB/BB.

Hope the above description was accurate, if not then i will try and post a better detailed hand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There must always be a BB. Treatment of the small blind varies with club rules, but tournaments pretty consistently use "dead button" rules, which means that the SB is paid by the person who paid the BB last hand if he's still in the game, and simply skipped if not.

Answer (score 1):

Look up dead button rule

```
1     2    3    4     5
bnt   sb   bb   utg   utg+1

co    btn  xx   sb    bb      opt A

co    btn  sb   bb            opt B
```

The problem with opt A is 4 does not pay a big blind
With opt B there is no sb paid

Option B - just post a BB is the common approach

[dead button](http://www.homepokertourney.com/button.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If he busted the hand he played as the UTG player then the BB goes to the next person. If he busted in his BB then there is just one BB next hand